# Trying to figure out how to get touch events for Android

Tags: android, events, touch

I'm making a game that has a 9 by 10 grid that is drawn in a view.  This works, I would like to be able to detect when a user touches one of the cells. I know how to get keyboard events.  I figure there must be a way to get a touch even with the x,y cordernat for my view with the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) on your `View` object. The single method to implement gets the `MotionEvent` parameter. It gives you the actual coords of the touch event. See the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html).

Comment: Can't say anything better than that!

Comment: Hi,Thank you for replying, bvut I still cannot get it to work.et a bvreak point in the OnTouchListener body and it never goes off.public codeclass cGameBoard extends View {
    int h;
    
 boolean OnTouchListener( MotionEvent event )
 {
  
 h=6;  // break point 
  return true;
 }

Answer (score 0):

Together with setting [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) on your View object don't forget to set other views that your principle view is inside. For instance, if your layout is a LinearLayout and a Button, do you have to set OnTouchListener for both, LinearLayout and Button.